Column value update issue
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
data = {'FFC': [200, 52880],
    'CLUB': [0, 0],
    'PBC': [200, 0],
    'ESC': [200, 0],
    'LPLC': [250, 0],
    'FPLC': [0, 0],
    'Other ServiceTax': [105, 5447]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define multiplier values for specific columns
multiplier_values = {'FFC': [0.1030, 0.1236, 0.14], 
                     'PBC': [0.1030, 0.1236, 0.14],
                     'ESC': [0.1030, 0.1236, 0.14], 
                     'LPLC': [0.1030, 0.1236, 0.14],
                     'FPLC': [0.1030, 0.1236, 0.14],
                     'CLUB': [0.1030, 0.1236, 0.14],}

for col, multipliers in multiplier_values.items():
    for multiplier in multipliers:
        new_column_name = f'{col}_{multiplier}'
        df[new_column_name] = (df[col] * multiplier)

numeric_columns = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'\d')]

# Create a list to store DataFrames and concatenate them at the end
result_dfs = []

# Generate all combinations of columns for each row individually
tolerance = 2
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    desired_sum = row['Other ServiceTax']
    all_combinations = [comb for r in range(1, len(numeric_columns) + 1) for comb in 
    combinations(numeric_columns, r)]
    
    for combination in all_combinations:
        subset_sum = row[list(combination)].sum()
        if abs(subset_sum - desired_sum) <= tolerance:
            result_row = row.copy()
            print(result_row)

            for col in combination:
                multiplier_value = float(col.split('_')[1])
                if row[col] != 0:
                    result_row[col] = multiplier_value
                else:
                    result_row[col] = 0
            print(result_row)
            exit()

Basically I want to find out the sum of combinations of values that should equal to the Other ServiceTax.
So this is the code for sample data, and this is not a complete code. But I am only facing problems in this last part.
So the problem I am facing is that it is splitting the first columns (FFC_0.103, FFC_0.1236, FFC_0.14) only and ignoring the rest of the columns with "_". And the reason for ignoring other columns with _ ,which I think is that the values of the other columns are the same as the first columns.
Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue?
Getting this:
FFC                 200.0000
CLUB                  0.0000
PBC                 200.0000
ESC                 200.0000
LPLC                250.0000
FPLC                  0.0000
Other ServiceTax    105.0000
FFC_0.103             0.1030
FFC_0.1236            0.1236
FFC_0.14              0.1400
PBC_0.103            20.6000
PBC_0.1236           24.7200
PBC_0.14             28.0000
ESC_0.103            20.6000
ESC_0.1236           24.7200
ESC_0.14             28.0000
LPLC_0.103           25.7500
LPLC_0.1236           0.1236
LPLC_0.14            35.0000
FPLC_0.103            0.0000
FPLC_0.1236           0.0000
FPLC_0.14             0.0000
CLUB_0.103            0.0000
CLUB_0.1236           0.0000
CLUB_0.14             0.0000

Expected Output:
FFC                 200.0000
CLUB                  0.0000
PBC                 200.0000
ESC                 200.0000
LPLC                250.0000
FPLC                  0.0000
Other ServiceTax    105.0000
FFC_0.103             0.1030
FFC_0.1236            0.1236
FFC_0.14              0.1400
PBC_0.103             0.1030
PBC_0.1236            0.1236
PBC_0.14              0.1400
ESC_0.103             0.1030
ESC_0.1236            0.1236
ESC_0.14              0.1400
LPLC_0.103            0.1030
LPLC_0.1236           0.1236
LPLC_0.14             0.1400
FPLC_0.103            0.0000
FPLC_0.1236           0.0000
FPLC_0.14             0.0000
CLUB_0.103            0.0000
CLUB_0.1236           0.0000
CLUB_0.14             0.0000




Can you please [edit] your question and put there expected output?

I don't understand your expected output. If I multiply those values by the FFC etc. values and sum the result I get 311.61

which values by the FFC?

The multiplier values

I think you are doing some wrong calculation.
It's 2000.1030= 20.60 , 2000.1236=24.72, 200*0.14 = 28.00

@arvin Can you please check again your data is correct? Your expected output seems to consist of only the values from the multiplier_values dictionary. Also, consider learning a bit about pandas best practices. E.g., since the multiplier_values are already structured like a dataframe, you could multiply all values of a row with a single operation like so df.loc[0] * pd.DataFrame(multiplier_values). Also also, consider telling us a bit more about what you are actually trying to achieve (cf. XY problem).

So I want to find the value of "?". The value of "?" is one of these 0.1030, 0.1236, 0.1400.
Now how to calculate the value of "?"
First, we need to multiply each value in each column by 0.1030, 0.1236, and 0.1404. Then we need to sum up the result in such a way that the sum up value must be equal or approximately equal to Other ServiceTax valve.
With this we will be able to identify what are the tax values.
I've included images that demonstrate the process and the outcome.
